# parse json with embedded lists into semi-long dataframe

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I have a json file with several layers of nesting, and I am struggling to get it into a workable dataframe. I created a toy example of mock data based on a real structure: [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ericpgreen/ccea4860567206940783e3ed27d78d2a/raw/3e3111d0308734da1ef762f7f0ee7a36a3d67f08/example.json) is the gist.

And here is my desired output. The output could be "longer" or have additional variables from the original json, but I'm showing the core ask.

[image]

This is the part of the json that shows the deepest level of nesting that I want to get into a semi-long format as shown above in white (a fully wide format would be fine).

[image]

I've tried lots of things with this object:

```
myList <- jsonlite::fromJSON("example.json", flatten=TRUE)$results
```

from trying to subset `[][[]]` and `cbind()`, to other efforts trying to unnest the embedded lists. Nothing quite right. I'd benefit greatly from advice on the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this get you any further along? (This is a gnarly structure):

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- (jsonlite::fromJSON("/Users/hrbrmstr/r7/gh/labs-research/2018-11-portland-ciso-event/example.json"))

jsonlite::stream_out(x$results, con = gzfile("ex-res.json.gz"))

y <- ndjson::stream_in("ex-res.json.gz", "tbl")

gather(y, path, path_val, starts_with("path")) %>%
  gather(flow, flow_val, starts_with("flow")) %>%
  gather(name, name_val, starts_with("values.pdep")) %>%
  gather(intervention, interv_val, starts_with("values.inter")) %>%
  glimpse()
## Observations: 87,696
## Variables: 18
## $ contact.name <chr> "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 1", "Person 2"...
## $ contact.uuid <chr> "k0dcjs", "rd3jfui", "k0dcjs", "rd3jfui", "k0dcjs", "rd3jfui", "k0dcjs", "rd3jfui", "k0dcjs", ...
## $ created_on   <chr> "2016-02-08T07:00:15.093813Z", "2016-02-08T07:00:15.093813Z", "2016-02-08T07:00:15.093813Z", "...
## $ id           <dbl> 1234, 1235, 1234, 1235, 1234, 1235, 1234, 1235, 1234, 1235, 1234, 1235, 1234, 1235, 1234, 1235...
## $ modified_on  <chr> "2016-02-09T04:42:54.812323Z", "2016-02-08T08:09:51.545160Z", "2016-02-09T04:42:54.812323Z", "...
## $ responded    <lgl> TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE...
## $ start.uuid   <chr> "dnxh4g", "kfj4dsi", "dnxh4g", "kfj4dsi", "dnxh4g", "kfj4dsi", "dnxh4g", "kfj4dsi", "dnxh4g", ...
## $ uuid         <chr> "esn4dk", "qask9dj", "esn4dk", "qask9dj", "esn4dk", "qask9dj", "esn4dk", "qask9dj", "esn4dk", ...
## $ exit_type    <chr> NA, "completed", NA, "completed", NA, "completed", NA, "completed", NA, "completed", NA, "comp...
## $ exited_on    <chr> NA, "2016-02-08T08:09:51.544998Z", NA, "2016-02-08T08:09:51.544998Z", NA, "2016-02-08T08:09:51...
## $ path         <chr> "path.0.node", "path.0.node", "path.0.time", "path.0.time", "path.1.node", "path.1.node", "pat...
## $ path_val     <chr> "ecb4cb11-6cca-4791-a950-c448e9300846", "ecb4cb11-6cca-4791-a950-c448e9300846", "2016-02-08T07...
## $ flow         <chr> "flow.name", "flow.name", "flow.name", "flow.name", "flow.name", "flow.name", "flow.name", "fl...
## $ flow_val     <chr> "weeklyratings", "weeklyratings", "weeklyratings", "weeklyratings", "weeklyratings", "weeklyra...
## $ name         <chr> "values.pdeps1.category", "values.pdeps1.category", "values.pdeps1.category", "values.pdeps1.c...
## $ name_val     <chr> "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 - 7", "0 -...
## $ intervention <chr> "values.intervention", "values.intervention", "values.intervention", "values.intervention", "v...
## $ interv_val   <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA...
```

Full approach:

```
gather(y, path, path_val, starts_with("path")) %>%
  gather(flow, flow_val, starts_with("flow")) %>%
  gather(name, name_val, starts_with("values.pdep")) %>%
  gather(intervention, interv_val, starts_with("values.inter")) %>%
  filter(grepl(".value", name)) %>% 
  filter(grepl("node", path)) %>%
  mutate(variable = gsub("values.", "", name)) %>% 
  mutate(variable = gsub(".value", "", variable)) %>% 
  distinct(contact.name, uuid, name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(id, uuid, contact.uuid, variable, name_val, created_on, modified_on) %>% 
  arrange(id, created_on) # optional wide %>% spread(variable, name_val)
```

Comment: Awesome, @hrbmstr! I was able to take this and get it the rest of the way. Shall I make an edit to your answer to suggest the method?

Comment: messy as a comment, but replace `glimpse()` with: `filter(grepl(".value", name)) %>% filter(grepl("node", path)) %>% mutate(variable = gsub("values.", "", name)) %>% mutate(variable = gsub(".value", "", variable)) %>% distinct(contact.name, uuid, name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% select(id, uuid, contact.uuid, variable, name_val, created_on, modified_on) %>% arrange(id, created_on) # optional wide %>% spread(variable, name_val)`

Comment: definitely go ahead and edit it. just glad it helped. i've had my share of gnarly json in the past.